# image is not rendered though its shown in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I'm working on Xamarin studio 6.1.1 and am building a native Xamarin.iOS app, on the LaunchScreen.storyboard file I have two UIImageViews, assigned image for each one from image assets.
the problem is when I run my app one of the two images is shown and another one is not though both are shown in the storyboard file.

I have placed all my images directly in the Resource folder and made sure that there is nothing missing, The scenario is soo simple and I'm not sure what the reason behind this.

[image: Storyboard file]
[image: Simulator view]

Comment: The issue is with layouts, your images are overlapping

Comment: Fine, i want them to be overlapped

Comment: We need more information to help. Post the images, to see how they look like, or describe it (has green background, is transparent. Also, dscribe how the views overlap and how they are setup (backgroundColor == clear?)...

Comment: set constriants properly to subviews , i think you are missing some constriants